# keen-slider does not work on next.js well

Tags: reactjs, slider, next.js

I am trying to change the following code that works as shown in the below screenshot to slider form using keen-slider.

[image]

```
        <div className="card-con mt-6">
          {!loadingImages &&
            nftDataArr.map((ele, index) => {
              return (
                <div className="lg:w-3/12 md:w-3/12 w-full"
                  key={index}>
                  <div className="card">
                    <div className="card__cover cursor-pointer">                      
                      <Image
                        src = {ele.image}
                        placeholder="/img/cover/cover5.jpg"
                        className="card__image"
                        width="auto"
                        height="300"
                        />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              )
            }
          )};
        </div>
```

So I changed the code following:

```
      <div ref={sliderRef} className="keen-slider">            
        {!loadingImages &&
          nftDataArr.map((ele, index) => {
            return (
              <div className="keen-slider__slide">
                <div className="w-full"
                  key={index}>
                  <div className="card">
                    <div className="card__cover cursor-pointer">                      
                      <Image
                        src = {ele.image}
                        placeholder="/img/cover/cover5.jpg"
                        className="card__image"
                        width="auto"
                        height="300"
                        />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            )
          }
        )};
      </div>
```

But keen-slider does not work, cards show like the below screenshot.
[image]

Please let me know what I did wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem.
I managed to fix it by just making
the options object for the useKeenSlider() as a
empty state object. When I get my items through useEffect()
I then set the object with the properties I need. It seems
that triggers the ref to update and so updates the slide.

```
const [options,setOptions] = useState({});
const [sliderRef, slider] = useKeenSlider(options);
const [slides, setSlides] = React.useState([]);


useEffect(()=>{
var data = getDataValues();
setSlides(data);
setOptions({
    slidesPerView: 1,
    mode: "free-snap",
    centered: true,
    loop: false,
    initial: 0,
    slideChanged(s) {
      setCurrentSlide(s.details().relativeSlide);
    },
  });
})
```

Comment: wow clever! I knew the problem but didn't know how to solve it! thx

Answer (score 3):

Keen Slider needs the slides to calculate bounds on initialization, any slides added after creation won't be taken into account and `slider.update()` would have to be called. But since you only have on state which says whether or not the images are rendered, you could just wrap the slider as its whole within your condition:

```
{!loadingImages && (
   <div ref={sliderRef} className="keen-slider">
      ...
   </div>      
)}
```

Or as mentioned before call `slider.update()` when the images are ready. To avoid flickering you could add `visibility: hidden` correspondingly.

Comment: Thanks!  However, I didn't find the necessity to call: ```slider.update()```

Answer (score 1):

You can update the slider this way:

```
const [ref, internalSlider] = useKeenSlider({...})
useEffect(() => {
   internalSlider?.current?.update();
}, [elements]);
```

That was the solution for me.

Comment: yeah, you are right. It works for me in this way too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had with the keen-slider is that my API call would load the images in after the slider has been rendered, keen-slider didn't like that. How I solved this was to run my GQL call in a parent component then once finished loading pass the results to a slider child component where keen-slider is held. In addition to that while its loading I just show a loading icon.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).