# keen-slider does not work well with fetch data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, slider, render

I want to fetch public data and display them using keen-slider. However it doesn't seem to work very well, especially when I tried to add in left-right arrows. They won't show up. Another issue is that the sliders freeze on first load and only move after the window is resized.

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [options, setOptions] = useState({});
  const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(0);
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [sliderRef, instanceRef] = useKeenSlider(options);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("./data.json")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
        setData(json);
      });
    setOptions({
      initial: 0,
      slides: {
        origin: "center",
        perView: "3",
        spacing: 25
      },

      slideChanged(slider) {
        setCurrentSlide(slider.track.details.rel);
      },
      created() {
        setLoaded(true);
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

Please see the complete code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-butterfly-d4vp5k?file=/src/App.js).

I followed the suggestion in these [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67992371/keen-slider-does-not-work-on-next-js-well) [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72554713/keen-slider-doesnt-work-well-with-server-side-render-on-the-first-render-next) to update the options in `useKeenSlider` when I fetch the data. It helped to mitigate an error message but didn't solve the issue completely.

I also followed the example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/rcbyr/keen-slider-sandboxes/tree/v6/navigation-controls/arrows-and-dots/react?file=/src/App.js)  to add in the arrow.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think your mapping data fail , all result is:

`<div className="keen-slider__slide number-slide1">1</div>`
But we desired result is :

```
<div className="keen-slider__slide number-slide1">1</div>
      <div className="keen-slider__slide number-slide2">2</div>
      <div className="keen-slider__slide number-slide3">3</div>
      <div className="keen-slider__slide number-slide4">4</div>
      <div className="keen-slider__slide number-slide5">5</div>
      <div className="keen-slider__slide number-slide6">6</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can solve this problem with the condition, if we have data then you can show the keen-slider else show a loading

```
{
  data ? <slider></slider> : <p>loading...</p>
}
```